# Font-awesome is not loading in IE

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, primeng

I am working in a angular 2 App Font-awesome icons is not loading in IE. I am using the following versions. And it is working fine in chrome and firefox

```
Node V7.2.1
npm v3.10.10
Typescript v2.2.1
webpack 2.2.1
font-awesome v4.7.0
```

And i have added the font-awesome css in vendor.ts file

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

loaded the loader in webpack.config.js

```
{
  test: /\.(woff|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9])?$/,
   loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
 },
```

Comment: Please check if you haveany kind of adblock plugin in your IE.

Comment: No and it also not working for Edge browser also